# Making a visualization of ingame map and NPC positions with Three.js involving some math such as remapping of positions but the result is incorrect

Tags: javascript, express, unity-game-engine, socket.io, three.js

I have made a simple plugin for the game Rust that dumps out the color information for the ingame map and NPC coordinates to datafile on a interval.

The map size ranges from -2000 to 2000 in the X and Z axis so the NPC coordinates X and Z also ranges from -2000 to 2000.

In three.js i have a PlaneBufferGeometry representing the map that is setup like this:

```cs
const mapGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2, 2, 2000, 2000 ); // width,height,width segments,height segments

mapGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 ); // rotate the geometry to match the scene

const customUniforms = {
    bumpTexture: { value: heightTexture },
    bumpScale:      { type: "f", value: 0.02 },
    colorTexture:   { value: colorTexture }
};

const mapMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: customUniforms,
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    wireframe:true
});

const mapMesh = new THREE.Mesh( mapGeometry, mapMaterial );

scene.add( mapMesh );
```

The webpage is served with express server with socket.io integration.

The server emits updated coordinates to the connected clients on an interval.

```js
socket.on('PositionData', function(data) {
    storeNPCPositions(data);
});
```

I'm iterating over the NPC data and try to remap the coordinates to correspond with the setup in Three.js like this:

```js
function storeNPCPositions(data) {
    let npcs = [];
    for (const npc in data.npcPositions) {
        npcs.push({
            name: npc,
            position: {
                x: remapPosition(data.npcPositions[npc].x, -2000, 2000, -1, 1), // i am uncertain about the -1 to 1 range, maybe 0 to 2?
                y: remapPosition(data.npcPositions[npc].y, heightData.min, heightData.max, 0, .02),
                z: remapPosition(data.npcPositions[npc].z, -2000, 2000, -1, 1), // i am uncertain about the -1 to 1 range, maybe 0 to 2?
            }
        });
    }
    window.murkymap.positionData.npcs = npcs;
}

function remapPosition(value, from1, to1, from2, to2)
{
    return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
}
```

As you can see in the code above in the `storeNPCPositions` function I have commented some uncertainty regarding the remapping, but either way it is wrong placement in the end result.

The image below is what I got right now, the npc's are not in the correct positions.
[image: Screenshot of the generated map and red capsules representing NPC's]

I hope that anyone can see the error in my code, i've been at it for many hours now.

Comment: Why don't you just nest all minimap elements together [in a group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group), then just scale down the group? `group.add(npcObject); group.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);` Then you should be able to assign the same positions, without needing to do any mapping.

Comment: Hi thanks! The problem is that the unit system in the game differs from Three.js. What i did was rewrite all in Three.js matching the scale of the game map. The actual problem was that the player positions was flipped on the X axis. I just found out and it is all working now :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the NPC positions were flipped on the X axis. I made a `THREE.Object3D()` and added all the NPC's to that and then flipped it like this:

```
let npcContainer = new THREE.Object3D();
npcContainer.position.set(0,0,0);
npcContainer.rotateX(Math.PI);

let npcs = [];

const npcLineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});

for (let i = 0; i < window.murkymap.positionData.npcs.length; i++) {
    const npc = window.murkymap.positionData.npcs[i];
    const npcPoints = [];
    npcPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(npc.position.x, 1000, npc.position.z));
    npcPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(npc.position.x,200,npc.position.z));
    npcPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(npc.position.x,-50,npc.position.z));
    const npcLineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( npcPoints );
    const npcLine = new THREE.Line(npcLineGeometry, npcLineMaterial);
    npcLine.position.y = -750;
    npcLine.name = "npc";
    npcLine.userData.prefab = npc.name;
    npcs.push(npcLine);
}

npcContainer.remove(...npcContainer.children);
npcContainer.add(...npcs);
scene.add(npcContainer);
```

[image: Red lines represent the position of NPC's on the map]